# Can't format column

Tags: xml, vba

I am converting xml file into worksheet but for some reason there is no option to convert the column to any other date format any idea why ?[image]

Comment: I think Excel does not recognise your data as a date. you'll need to parse it manually first.

Comment: Please, test the code I posted. The specific format you use, is obviously not recognize by Excel as `Date`. The posted code process the string and extracts date in a new inserted column. The code  can delete the existing column, but it better you to check it and delete if the conversion is exactly as you need...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code to translate the text in Date:

```
Sub TransformTextInDate()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngT As Range, arrT, ArrD, arr, i As Long
  
  Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need, or activate the one to be processed
  lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row
  
  Set rngT = sh.Range("A2:A" & lastR)    'use here your range to be converted in Date
  arrT = rngT.value                      'load the range in an array
  ReDim ArrD(1 To UBound(arrT), 1 To 1)  'redim the array to keep Date
  
  For i = 1 To UBound(arrT)
     If ArrT(i, 1) <> "" Then
        arr = Split(arrT(i, 1), "-")     'split the text by "-"
        ArrD(i, 1) = DateSerial(CLng(arr(0)), CLng(arr(1)), CLng(left(arr(2), 2))) 'build the Date
     End If
  Next i
  rngT.Offset(0, 1).EntireColumn.Insert xlLeft  'insert a column to the right of the processed one
  With sh.cells(rngT.row, rngT.Offset(0, 1).Column).Resize(UBound(ArrD), 1)
        .Value2 = ArrD                   'drop the processed array values at once
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit            'fit the new column
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd"     'format the range in the standard way
  End With
  MsgBox "Converted to Date..."
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it...

Comment: Hi
Why it's not possible to format the column by simple format code line ?

Comment: @Shlomo: Yes, it can be done but it will not be efficient... It is faster doing it at once for all range! The code does not format "all column". It is formatting the column range having data... If you try referring to the existing column, is is obviously impossible. In order to be fast, the code puts the range in an array. Iteration between array elements is much faster. Writing the value of each cell takes time and consumes Excel resources, which means less speed, more resources consumed. But, **didn't the above code do what you need**?

Comment: Thanks i am new to VBA... i will try it

Comment: @Shlomo: I cannot understand why you did not try it... Anyhow, we here when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works. Our main goal here is to make as many people as possible learning...

Comment: Hi FaneFuru
I still didn't finish to combine with my code and like i already said before i will update. I fully understand that this code can help others.

Comment: @Shlomo: What to "combine with your code"? Did you try the code **as it is**? Does it convert the text in date in a newly inserted column, or not? Did you try it?

Comment: I have a problem when there are no values in some of the column cells can you tell how to solve it?

Comment: @Shlomo: Yes, not so complicated. You should firstly check if the array element is empty. In fact, I will adapt the above code to specifically treat such cases... Please, test the updated code and send some feedback.

Comment: Hi FaneDuru 
Perfect ! Thank you very much